# How to check last executed query in Opencart3

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart-3

```
$data['module_status'] = $this->config->get('visit_module_enabled');
```

I need to check what query is executed in $this->config->get.
And anyhow, just like code Igniter has an option $this->db->last_query() ,
don't we have something similar in Opencart3 ?

If this is the original Db object, are those really all the functions we have for $this->db object?
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/db.php

Or perhaps some implementation in core PHP or mysql to achieve the same?

Comment: Do you have VQMOD on the installation?

Comment: @Daniel :: not right now, but what if i had? Is there a way?

Comment: Yes, if you had it, I have a VQMOD xml file that logs queries executed and duration of execution that I use when troubleshooting performance. Seems that @billynoah answered your question though

Comment: can you please anyway, share the xml for future use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... just like code Igniter has an option `$this->db->last_query()` , don't we have something similar in Opencart3 ?

**No.** Opencart is not a framework (like CodeIgniter) and doesn't offer as robust a library of functions.

> If this is the original Db object, are those really all the functions we have for $this->db object?

**Yes.**

> I need to check what query is executed in $this->config->get

That doesn't make any sense.  `$this->config->get()` simply gets the value of an array key of the `$data` property of the `config` class.  All of those properties are loaded on site initialization.  Most of them (not all) come from this query in `controller/startup/startup.php`:

```
SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "setting` WHERE store_id = '0' OR store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY store_id ASC
```

If you want to know where that specific value came from it's most likely going to be in the `setting` table where `key = 'visit_module_enabled'`.

If you still want to create a `last_query()` method, it would be very easy, but based on your question I don't think it's going to get you what you want.

To create a `last_query()` method, you can modify the `db` class like this:

```php
private $last_query;

public function query($sql) {
    $this->last_query = $sql;
    return $this->adaptor->query($sql);
}

public function last_query() {
    return $this->last_query;
}
```

Comment: where could i create a method and how? you're suggesting i should store every query i get to the function $this->db->query() in a file or something?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a VQMOD xml file to log the SQL queries executed by OpenCart and the duration to execute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <id>SYSTEM MYSQLI DB LOG vQmod for OC 2.x</id>
    <code>sculptex_mysqli_db_log</code>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <vqmver required="true">2.5.1</vqmver>
    <author>Sculptex</author>

    <file name="system/library/db/mysqli.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[public function query($sql) {]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
$logfile = DIR_LOGS."SQL_log.txt";
$starttime  = microtime(true);
]]></add>
        </operation>

        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[return $result;]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
$endtime  = microtime(true);
$log = sprintf(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time())." QUERY EXECUTED IN %0.4f - %s", $endtime-$starttime, $sql);
if(!file_exists($logfile)) { file_put_contents($logfile,''); }
$f = fopen($logfile, 'a');
fwrite($f, $log."\n");
fclose($f);
                ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

</modification>
```

I'm not the original author of this mod and found it years ago on the forum. As far as I can see it will work for OpenCart 3.

I'd caution against setting this and leaving it as the log file grows very quickly.

Comment: opencart3 seemingly uses pdo, instead of mysqli. so I make a new version of this xml: https://github.com/scil/study_opencart/blob/main/upload/vqmod/xml/db_pdo_log.xml